# get string from pandas column shorter than real

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a df like this:

| Sucursal | url |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moov/@-34.4718341,-58.5170394,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x95bcb1c7fd6203c3:0x37a2af54c5fe1a!8m2!3d-34.4718341!4d-58.5148507 |
| 11 | https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moov/@-34.6496456,-58.6220989,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x95bcc7612176b9a3:0x2c6fcf2164a536b9!8m2!3d-34.6496453!4d-58.6199217 |

(Real df has more than 100 rows)

I´m using Selenium to get some reviews from google, so I need to loop the urls from  "url" column.

This is the first part of the script :

```
    for i in (range(0,2)): #I´m testing with some elements to see if it works
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        url=str(df.iloc[[i]]['url']).split()[1]        
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]/button').click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

and so on

the problem is when I get the driver, the url pasted in the rendered page is : "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moov/@-34.4718341,-58.5170394,17z"

It happens the same with all urls strings...I don´t know why it´s not getting 100% of the string.
If I print  as value:

```
print(df['url'].values)
```

The url string is ok...but not when it opens the chrome driver...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are `url` and `url_google_maps` different columns?

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. Are the same. I changed the column name to be shorter. The problem is the same, and column of the example is "url"

Answer (score -1):

I used `tsv` file to generate `df` based on your data

```py
import contextlib
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
# path to your chromedriver
service = Service(executable_path='your-path')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

df = pandas.read_csv('grev.tsv', sep='\t')

# accept cookies
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps')
with contextlib.suppress(TimeoutException):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'form[action]:nth-child(2)'))).click()

# open links from df and get reviews
for url in df['url']:
    driver.get(url)
    # click on the "More" button for reviews
    driver.execute_script("for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll('jsl>button')) {elem.click()}")
    # get the first 3 reviews
    reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-review-id]:first-child')
    for review in reviews:
        print(review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="MyEned"]').text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Lenta, but I don´t see how to solve my problem here? I read a .xlsx and convert it to a DF. the DF has columns, I need to iterate through each  item of df[url]...but when I get each element via url=str(df.iloc[[i]]['url']).split()[1], I don´t get the complete link... I only need to solve this, Not to modify script , css selectors or xpath... I only need to get the complete str link to iterate

Comment: If you want to use `iloc` then set pandas options `display.max_colwidth` to 255 or something, default is 50. `pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 255)`